# Using Three.JS VOXLoader on Flask

Tags: javascript, flask, three.js

I apologize in advance if I'm missing something obvious here.
I'm trying to use the three.js VOXLoader while using Flask.

I'm able to load three.js fine, but when I try and load the VOXLoader, it doesn't seem to work and breaks all three.js functionality on the page.

Here is the code from the page I'm trying to run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>ThreeJS Starter</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="/static/three/build/three.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/static/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/static/three/examples/jsm/loaders/VOXLoader.js"></script>


<script type="module">

    // Canvas
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

    // Scene
    const scene = new THREE.Scene()
    
    // Problem Loading Here
    const loader = new VOXLoader();

    const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( .7, .2, 16, 100 );

    // Materials

    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()
    material.color = new THREE.Color(0xff0000)

    // Mesh
    const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material)
    scene.add(sphere)

    // Lights

    const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.1)
    pointLight.position.x = 2
    pointLight.position.y = 3
    pointLight.position.z = 4
    scene.add(pointLight)

    /**
     * Sizes
     */
    const sizes = {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', () =>
    {
        // Update sizes
        sizes.width = window.innerWidth
        sizes.height = window.innerHeight

        // Update camera
        camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

        // Update renderer
        renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
        renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
    })

    /**
     * Camera
     */
    // Base camera
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
    camera.position.x = 0
    camera.position.y = 0
    camera.position.z = 2
    scene.add(camera)

    // Controls
    // const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas)
    // controls.enableDamping = true

    /**
     * Renderer
     */
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: canvas
    })
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))

    /**
     * Animate
     */

    const clock = new THREE.Clock()

    const tick = () =>
    {

        const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()

        // Update objects
        sphere.rotation.y = .5 * elapsedTime

        // Update Orbital Controls
        // controls.update()

        // Render
        renderer.render(scene, camera)

        // Call tick again on the next frame
        window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
    }

    tick()

</script>

TEST
<canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
```

Currently, when the page loads correctly it displays a red spinning Torus, but if it doesn't it show a white background with black text saying "TEST".

Ideally, I should be able to create a new instance of the VOXLoader without it breaking the page.
I've tried adding "import { VOXLoader } from '/static/three/examples/jsm/loaders/VOXLoader.js';" too, but the import function alone also seems to break the page.
I also checked the three.js documentation but didn't find anything helpful there yet.
It seems most people using three.js, aren't typically using it with flask, so I'm not sure if this is flask specific?

What's confusing to me is that the three.js file is imported fine and works with no issues, but for some reason, VOXLoader doesn't.
I double-checked the path and directory for VOXLoader and it's 100% correct.
This page is also currently only being used as a template for other pages to extend from, so it doesn't have any python code on it either.

I'm just trying to get the VOXLoader working and any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is usually error in the console that says what's wrong

Comment: Thanks for the tip, my tunnel vision got so bad, I forgot about the console in the browser too.

The browser console only has 2 errors:
1) - Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

2) - (index):30 Uncaught ReferenceError: VOXLoader is not defined
    at (index):30:24
(anonymous) @ (index):30

So it seems it's not importing the function from the module then?
Is there another way I might be able to import it?